# Cannot Deploy Field: Picklist value is too long for the max size of 40

Tags: deployment, change-set, platform-bug

I'm trying to do a deployment on to a sandbox and I'm getting an odd error:

[image]

> Picklist value is too long for the max size of 40

As far as I know this limit has been removed for some time and confirm this buy manually adding a picklist value of up to 255 characters.  This is a custom field.

Same error if I try to deploy with ant.

**Is this a platform bug or am I missing something?**

(PS: this is causing our continuous integration builds to fail so it's really more annoying than it should be)

Comment: I think 40 characters per value is still a limitation for a standard picklist field. 150 for custom field.

Comment: So you can add the value in the UI with more than 40 characters but not through the API? Weirdo!

Comment: This is a custom picklist field.  Updated my question to reflect that

Comment: The newest comments describe the same. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KSkNAAW

Answer (score 1):

Apperently when they removed the picklist limit from the UI they didn't remember to remove the validations from the deployment API's.

[Official Statement](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Spring-16-Picklist-value-is-too-long-for-the-max-size-of-40-via-API-but-not-in-the-User-Interface&language=en_US):

---

> In Spring '16 as part of supporting Global Picklists (Pilot program,
>   more information here), we stopped enforcing the 40 character limit
>   for multi-select value labels. However, there are a few remaining
>   places in the API where there still is validation enforcing these
>   limits. We will consider removing these limits in the future but in
>   the meantime you'd need to create those values manually or pass values
>   under 40 characters.

---

Guess my CI isn't going to successfully build anytime soon :(